# Twilio Outgoing call using Twiml - How do I wait for voicemail?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have successfully configured Postman to make a test call using variables in the Twiml parameter. However, when it goes to voicemail, the message has already played through. For example, in a longer Say message, the beginning is cut off in the recorded message.

How would I wait for voicemail "answer" when there is no human answer?

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC05917c014691f7d218d20XXXXXXX/Calls' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZjExZDIwM2IzOTYwMjUzYQ==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'To=1484xxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'From=1610xxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'Twiml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response>     <Pause length="2"/><Say voice="Polly.Salli-Neural">" Hello world  
</Say>     <Pause length="2"/>      </Response>'
```

Comment: Can you post the request you're trying to make and the Function code

Comment: thanks! I was able to get a {{name}} parameter through. However, now my question is about the case when it goes to voicemail.